# Pandas: Three listed columns to wide format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to expand a set of columns using the first column's values as headers for the other columns?

For example:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame({'id':[11,998,3923], 'count':[7,7,7],
  'attributes':['VIS,TEMP,MIN','MIN,VIS,TEMP','MIN,VIS'],
  'attribute_values':['0,4,2','2,3,0','0,9'],
  'attribute_years':['2000,2001,2002','2001,2002,2003','2008,2009']})
```

(**Edit:** note that attributes could be out of order or missing.)

| index | id | count | attributes | attribute_values | attribute_years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | 7 | VIS,TEMP,MIN | 0,4,2 | 2000,2001,2002 |
| 1 | 998 | 7 | MIN,VIS,TEMP | 2,3,0 | 2001,2002,2003 |
| 2 | 3923 | 7 | MIN,VIS | 0,9 | 2008,2009 |

In this case, the `attributes` column values should used to make new columns with `attribute_values` and `attribute_years` columns.

Ideal output:

| index | id | count | attribute_values_VIS | attribute_values_TEMP | attribute_values_MIN | attribute_years_VIS | attribute_years_TEMP | attribute_years_MIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |
| 1 | 998 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 2002 | 2003 | 2001 |
| 2 | 3923 | 7 | 9 | NaN | 0 | 2009 | NaN | 2008 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Split the strings in attribute like columns around delimiter `,` to convert into lists, then `explode` to convert lists into individual rows, then `pivot` with columns=`attributes` to reshape, finally flatten the multindex using `map + join`

```
y = x.set_index(['id', 'count'])
y = y.apply(lambda s: s.str.split(',')).explode([*y])
y = y.pivot(columns='attributes')
y.columns = y.columns.map('_'.join)
y = y.reset_index()
```

---

```
>>> y
     id  count attribute_values_MIN attribute_values_TEMP attribute_values_VIS attribute_years_MIN attribute_years_TEMP attribute_years_VIS
0    11      7                    2                     4                    0                2002                 2001                2000
1   998      7                    2                     0                    3                2001                 2003                2002
2  3923      7                    0                   NaN                    9                2008                  NaN                2009
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no native function in pandas to split strings and create new columns from them. However, you can easily write your own little function.
Assuming your example

```py
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3],
'attributes': ['VIS,TEMP,MIN','MIN,VIS,TEMP','MIN,VIS'],
'attribute_values': ['0,4,2','2,3,0','0,9'],
'attribute_years': ['2000,2001,2002','2001,2002,2003','2008,2009']})
```

You can just loop over the rows, split the strings in the columns `x['attributes']`, `x['attribute_values']`, and `x['attribute_years']`, split the strings (always assuming that we don't need to fear different length and that `','` indicates the character to split the strings) and create a new dictionary. Collecting all dictionaries with the new key-value pairs, you can just build a new pandas.DataFrame and assign it to the original if you like:

```
data = []
for i, row in x.iterrows():
    # extract data
    att = row['attributes'].split(',')
    val = list(map(int, row['attribute_values'].split(',')))
    yrs = list(map(int, row['attribute_years'].split(',')))
    # create new dictionaries
    row_new = {f'attribute_values_{a}': v for a, v in zip(att, val)}
    row_new.update({f'attribute_years_{a}': y for a, y in zip(att, yrs)})
    # concatenate dictionaries and append to list
    data.append(row_new)
# create table from list of rows
pd.DataFrame(data, index=x.index)
```

output:

| attribute_values_VIS | attribute_values_TEMP | attribute_values_MIN | attribute_years_VIS | attribute_years_TEMP | attribute_years_MIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 4.0 | 2 | 2000 | 2001.0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.0 | 2 | 2002 | 2003.0 |
| 2 | 9 | NaN | 0 | 2009 | NaN |

Comment: Sure, the dictionary keys were previously not formatted as strings but that was fixed before you answered.